# The $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ bump function is $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^{n} \to \Bbb{R}$ be

\begin{align*}
f(x)=&\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 e^{\frac{-1}{1-\left|x\right|^{2}}} \quad & \left|x\right|<1\\
 0 \quad & \left|x\right|>1.
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
How can I show that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be easier to show that the function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\exp(-1/(1-|x|^2))$ is $C^\infty$. I recall using some sort of inductive argument to establish differentiability at the trouble point $x=0$ and $x=\pm 1$. (Induction to go down through the derivatives.)

Comment: Then you'll prove some lemma that $C^\infty$ even functions which have $f'(0)=0$ give $C^\infty$ functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when you "rotate" them.

Comment: This proof is on wikipedia either the page for bump functions or maybe the page for mollifiers or a related result. Its exactly the induction. Also if you do it for $\exp(-1/t)\mathbf 1_[0,\infty)$ then there's only one trouble point. This makes $f$ a  composition of smooth functions